# Implementing Store/Recall Features on Calculator Using State

Tags: haskell, state, calculator

The following code is given; it basically is a calculator that contains a stack of numbers and operations (didn't include operations code) and evaluates to the stack through change of state.

```
data InternalState = InternalState
    { stack :: [Double]
    , memory :: Double
    }
type CalcState = State InternalState
type Calculation = CalcState ()
pop :: CalcState Double
pop = state $ \st -> case stack st of
    [] -> (0.0,st)
    x:xs -> (x,st { stack = xs })
push :: Double -> CalcState ()
push d = modify  $ \st -> st { stack = d : stack st }
```

I want to implement a function `recall :: Calculation` and `store :: Calculation`, such that, given a stack of numbers, `store` takes the top number and remembers it (changes the InternalState to have `memory` equal to that top number. `recall` should push the single stored number onto the top of the stack of numbers.

My problem is, I don't know how I should use the state functions like `get`, `put`, etc. in order to modify the state appropriately. I can see that I would want to alter the state so as ONLY to change the memory (which otherwise stays 0.0 for all other operations of type `Calculation`). I started implementing `store` with

```
store = do
   x <- pop
   push x
```

because I know I have to take and put back the top value on the stack, but I have no idea how to use this value to change just the memory of the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recall = do
  x <- gets memory
  modify (\s -> InternalState (x : stack s) x)

store = do
  (x:xs) <- gets stack
  put $ InternalState xs x
```